# Laravel belongsToMany where doesn't have one of

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two tables: `categories` and `videos`, I then have a pivot table for these as it's a belongsToMany relationship.

What I'm trying to do is get all of the videos where there isn't a single instance of the video being in one of many categories.

e.g.

- Video 1 is in category 1, 2 and 3.
- Video 2 is in category 1 and 3.
- Video 3 is in category 1.

I want to get the video which is NOT in category 2 or 3, meaning this will return Video 3.

What I've tried so far, which doesn't give the intended result, this is because another row is still found for Video 1 and 2, as they are in Category 1:

```
Video::whereHas('categories', function($query) {
    $query->whereNotIn('category_id', [2,3]);
})->take(25)->get();
```

The query populated from this is:

```
select * from `videos` where exists (select * from `categories` inner join 
`category_video` on `categories`.`id` = `category_video`.`category_id` where 
`videos`.`id` = `category_video`.`video_id` and `category_id` != ? and 
`category_id` != ? and `categories`.`deleted_at` is null) and `videos`.`deleted_at` 
is null order by `created_at` desc limit 25
```

Comment: A bit of a dirty solution would be using 2 where not in statements, 1 for both categories.

Comment: Yeah I thought that but I literally have about 100 categories to filter by, guess I could always foreach?

Comment: Acually, even a where would return the same as whereNotIn, would it not?

Comment: mm you can try dump the generated query: `\DB::enableQueryLog(); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` tho.

Comment: I've added the query which is generated by the call, which shows that it is always going to find that match. I'm not even sure how you'd do this with just mysql

Answer (score 20):

You can use Eloquent's **whereDoesntHave()** constraint to get what you need:

```
// get all Videos that don't belong to category 2 and 3
Video::whereDoesntHave('categories', function($query) {
  $query->whereIn('id', [2, 3]);
})->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is still returning the same results :/

Comment: It can't give you the same results as it's a different query, You fetched videos that have at least one category other than 2 and 3. This one gives you videos that don't have category with id 2 or 3.

Comment: Well obviously not the exact results, but it's still returning videos which are either in category 2 or 3, as it's found in category 1.

Comment: Whats the query youre getting?

Comment: select * from `videos` where not exists (select * from `categories` inner join `category_video` on `categories`.`id` = `category_video`.`category_id` where `videos`.`id` = `category_video`.`video_id` and `category_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `categories`.`deleted_at` is null) and `videos`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc limit 25