# use where clauses to get data from join query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, where-clause

I am creating a system using Laravel and AngularJS where I assign tasks to users. Multiple tasks has multiple users and vice versa. In the Database, I have this tables:

task:
id | name

task_users:
id | task_id | user_id

users:
id | name

In my view, I display a particular task, using id of task table. I display a list of users (called unassigned users) who are not assigned to that particular task. When that user is assigned, it's name gets removed from the list.

To achieve this, I used this query:

```
    public static function remainingUser($task_id)
    {
    return \DB::table('users')
        ->leftjoin('task_users', 'task_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('users.id',
            'users.name as name'
        )
        ->where('task_id', '!=', $task_id)
        ->orWhere('task_id', null)
        ->get();
    }
```

Suppose I have this data

task:

id | name

1 | Task1

2 | Task2

3 | Task3

users:

id | name

1  | User1

2  | User2

3  | User3

4  | User4

5  | User5

6  | User6

7  | User7

8  | User8

9  | User9

10 | User10

task_users:

id | task_id | user_id

1  |    1    |    1

1  |    1    |    2

1  |    1    |    3

1  |    1    |    5

1  |    1    |    6

1  |    1    |    7

1  |    2    |    2

1  |    2    |    4

Now suppose I am displaying task details of task_id = 1 and I want to assign user 4 to this task. So my list of unassigned users should contain all the users who are not assigned this task. My query does not return the required data. I have also tried different conditions in where clause, but I do not get the correct required data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821403/laravel-belongstomany-where-doesnt-have-one-of) question/answer. If you have well set models, tables and relations that would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue exists because when you select from `Users`, you get all users `left Joined` with a single instance of tasks. So if `User1` has `Task1` and `Task2`, only `Task1` will be matched here, because it will match `User1` to the 1st row found for him within `task_users`. In order to list the unasigned users, your query would look similar to this:

```
public static function remainingUser($task_id)
{
return \DB::table('task_users')
    ->rightJoin('users', 'task_users.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select(
      \DB::raw("DISTINCT(`users`.`id`)"),
      'users.name as name'
    )
    ->where('task_id', '!=', $task_id)
    ->orWhere('task_id', null)
    ->get();
}
```